# Why is this for statement appending twice? Python

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, append, sum

```
alpha_sum = [2396, 780, 2022, 596]
alpha_b_sum = [2206, 828, 1962, 597]
results_alpha = [[145, 142, 142, 111, 121, 151, 111, 113, 121, 106, 67, 151, 57, 111, 106, 101, 111, 98, 142, 106, 83], [142, 106, 83, 69, 145, 121, 114], [69, 145, 121, 114, 57, 121, 111, 121, 151, 77, 121, 77, 101, 113, 142, 77, 113, 108, 83], [113, 108, 83, 77, 114, 101], [57, 106, 98, 101, 101, 108, 108, 77, 114, 106, 142, 57, 113, 67], [101, 121, 77, 121, 57, 142, 142, 114, 121]]
values_alpha= [145, 142, 142, 111, 121, 151, 111, 113, 121, 106, 67, 151, 57, 111, 106, 101, 111, 98, 142, 106, 83, 69, 145, 121, 114, 57, 121, 111, 121, 151, 77, 121, 77, 101, 113, 142, 77, 113, 108, 83, 77, 114, 101, 69, 151, 67, 57, 106, 98, 101, 101, 108, 108, 77, 114, 106, 142, 57, 113, 67, 77, 101, 121, 77, 121, 57, 142, 142, 114, 121]

for alpha, alpha_b in zip(alpha_sum,  alpha_b_sum):
    for i in range(len(values_alpha)):
        if alpha > alpha_b:  
            for element in results_alpha:
                length = len(element)
                if values_alpha[i:i+length] == element:
                    export.append('Alpha'+'\t'+'[%d, %d]' % (i, i+length-1)+'\n') 
                    #print '[%d,%d]' % (i, i+length-1)+'\n'
                else:
                    pass

print export
['Alpha\t[0, 20]\n', 'Alpha\t[18, 24]\n', 'Alpha\t[21, 39]\n', 'Alpha\t[37, 42]\n', 'Alpha\t[46, 59]\n', 'Alpha\t[61, 69]\n', 
 'Alpha\t[0, 20]\n', 'Alpha\t[18, 24]\n', 'Alpha\t[21, 39]\n', 'Alpha\t[37, 42]\n', 'Alpha\t[46, 59]\n', 'Alpha\t[61, 69]\n']
```

Why is it appending the data twice?

Whats going on here is a list of numbers → `values_alpha`? Within that list there are certain portions which were appended to → `results_alpha` so `results_alpha` has portions of `values_alpha`...

I'm trying to check if each element in `alpha_sum > alpha_b_sum` and if it is, add the positions that particular sequence occurred (element in `results_alpha`) within the original sequence (`values_alpha`). If not then just skip it, hence the `pass` statement.

Comment: The values `alpha` and `alpha_b` are only compared but never used as described.

Comment: Have you tried just stepping through your code with a debugger to see how `export` is being built sequentially?

Comment: i see what you mean . alpha_sum is the sum of each element in results_alpha. i'll add it in there

Answer (score 2):

Like Noah1989 said the values are iterated over but never used.
Because two values from alpha happened to be larger than their corresponding match in alpha_b the loop happened twice.

Try this

```
>>> for i in range(len(values_alpha)):
...     for element in results_alpha:
...         length = len(element)
...         if values_alpha[i:i+length] == element:
...             export.append('Alpha'+'\t'+'[%d, %d]' % (i, i+length-1)+'\n')
...             #print '[%d,%d]' % (i, i+length-1)+'\n'
...         else:
...             pass
...
>>> print export
['Alpha\t[0, 20]\n', 'Alpha\t[18, 24]\n', 'Alpha\t[21, 39]\n', 'Alpha\t[37, 42]\n', 'Alpha\t[46, 59]\n', 'Alpha\t[61, 69]\n']
```

Comment: i only want to add the values whose sum_alpha > sum_alpha_b . this is what i originally had in my function